# Async Jest test in vueJS lifecycle hook with Interval

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I would to understand how can i test my "auth/refresh" action in the "beforeCreate" hook with jest like below :

// main.vue

```
async beforeCreate() {
    let authTokenRefreshIntervalId;

    await this.$store.dispatch('auth/initialize');

    authTokenRefreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.$store.dispatch('auth/refresh').catch(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout');
        clearInterval(authTokenRefreshIntervalId);
      });
    }, 30 * 1000);
}
```

// main.spec.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { shallow, createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Main from '@/main';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('store-auth', () => {
  let store;
  let actions;
  let getters;

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      initialize: jest.fn(),
      refresh: jest.fn(),
      logout: jest.fn(),
    };

    getters = {
      isAuthenticated: jest.fn(),
    };

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        auth: {
          namespaced: true,
          actions,
          getters,
        },
      },
    });
  });

  it('dispatch initialize on beforeCreate hook', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(Main, { store, localVue });
    expect(actions.initialize).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('dispatch refresh on beforeCreate hook every 30s', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(Main, { store, localVue });
    jest.runTimersToTime(30 * 1000);
    expect(actions.refresh).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Jest say that the mocked function is not called.
I tried with `expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalled()` and it pass the test.
Where i'm wrong plz ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using async/await in your test also.

```
it('dispatch refresh on beforeCreate hook every 30s', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(Main, { store, localVue });
    jest.runTimersToTime(30 * 1000);
    await expect(actions.refresh).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

Comment: it doesn't work like this but i edit the first with your async/await suggestion, follow the gist : https://gist.github.com/davidlandais/63c6c409a680dd9d831cb683452e793b
and it's working. But i don't understand why, maybe the first promise need to be resolved first

Comment: Maybe you need to mock you lifecycle hook like [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/166)